# update nested object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB.I have read almost all relative posts but cannot find a proper answer for my case. Suppose you have the document:

```
{ "_id" : "5ad1..", 
"linkedin" : { "linkedinId" : "NB..J", "username" : "dolguldur",  
"followers":[{name:"John",email:"john@example.com},{name:"Elsa",email:"elsa@example.com}] 
} 
}
```

If a follower changes his email, how can i update his record with the new one;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$elemMatch` operator to select your desired nested object :

```
db.collection.update({
    followers: {
        $elemMatch: {
            name: _follower_name,
            email: _follower_email
        }
    }
}, {
    "followers.$.email": new_mail
});
```

The `$` positional operator will select the first nested object that match the filter in `$elemMatch` and update it.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. You saved my day(or week...)